# How to query two tables grouping by date and counting date registries for each table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am using Firebird 2.5 and I have two tables:

```
|----------TABLE_1---------|   |----------TABLE_2---------|
|   DATE_1   | SOME_INFO_1 |   |   DATE_2   | SOME_INFO_2 |
| 2015-05-01 |    Brazil   |   | 2015-04-10 |    Bread    |
| 2015-06-23 |   Paraguai  |   | 2015-05-01 |     Air     |
| 2015-05-01 |    Chile    |   | 2015-05-01 |    Water    |
| 2015-05-01 |  Argentina  |
```

I want to group this tables by date, in such way that I can count how much registries I have per date in each table. This is the expected result:

```
|----------------RESULT_TABLE----------------|
|    DATE    | COUNT_TABLE_1 | COUNT_TABLE 2 |
| 2014-04-10 |       0       |       1       |
| 2015-05-01 |       3       |       2       |
| 2015-06-23 |       1       |       0       |
```

I am trying this:

```
SELECT
  a.date_1,
  COUNT(a.date_1) AS count_table_1,
  COUNT(b.date_2) AS count_table_2
FROM
  table_1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table_2 b ON b.date_2 = a.date_1
GROUP BY
  a.date_1, b.date_2
ORDER BY
  a.date_1 ASC, b.date_2 ASC
```

And I am getting this as result:

```
|----------------RESULT_TABLE----------------|
|    DATE    | COUNT_TABLE_1 | COUNT_TABLE 2 |
| 2014-04-10 |       0       |       1       |
| 2015-05-01 |       6       |       6       |
| 2015-06-23 |       1       |       0       |
```

I am feeling that my SQL is a mess, but I can't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, aggregate the results in each table and then `join` using the `date` column.

```
select t1.date_1 as dt, isnull(t1_count,0), isnull(t2_count,0)
from
(SELECT date_1, count(*) as t1_count from table_1 group by date_1) t1
full outer join
(SELECT date_2, count(*) as t2_count from table_2 group by date_2) t2
on t1.date_1 = t2.date_2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. BTW, Firebird 2.5 do not have `isnull` function, you must use `COALESCE` function with same synthax.